# Vertical scroll bar for select box on FIREFOX

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am developping an intranet to work on local. I have got problem with Vertical scroll bar on Firefox. I do not get Vertical scroll bar. If values in select box are too many then some of them goes out of display. I do not understand why i am not getting Vertical scroll bar.

[1 http://www.thewebdesign.org/1aa.PNG](http://www.thewebdesign.org/1aa.PNG)

**this is the code i am using**

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

.myselectbox {

    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;


}
    option {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fef5e6;
        padding:8px;
        margin:5px;

        border-top: 1px solid #ebdac0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ebdac0;
        border-right: 1px solid #d6bb86;
        border-left: 1px solid #d6bb86;
    }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<select name="amount_no1" class="myselectbox" id="amount_no1" >
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
</select> 
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Browsers usually change the position of the options from displaying below the select element to above. Tested your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/t5pan/ everything is as normal in Chrome and FF 4.0 beta.

Comment: hi.  can you add more numbers to <option></option> and try it. It does not work on firefox.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?" The options don't display? Or they are hidden off the top of the screen? BTW: horizontal is this way `<>` and Vertical is this way `v^`

Comment: Stupid me.... yes i mean vertical. I mean it works but i can not see the whole select options. They are hidden sometimes at the top sometimes at the bottom of screen. (It depends where the select box on screen)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour and is controlled by the browser. You could look for some javascript replacement solutions for your select elements, or you could split up the amount of options over a number of selects. The most important thing is user accessibility when it comes to forms, if it is too big to display all options, make it smaller :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this must be a bug in Firefox. (I was able to get it without any CSS at all at one point, just having the right number of options.)